# Possible Fixes? Older Blender File ... UI interaction .... Constraints indicators appear but cannot survive drill down .. Foreboding Console Messages

Tags: constraints, versions, panel

Old file opened in 2.9. Modified circ@ ‎December ‎‎2018.

In the constraint panel I see 4 constraints listed.  They cannot be opened.  The error message in Console Window is listed below.  Some other strange behavior which is omitted for brevity and focus.  UI interaction when inspecting constraints.

Did format of constraints change from older file to newer files??

IndexError: bpy_prop_collection[index]: **index 3 out of range**, size 0

I am guessing at nebulous possible causes.

---

```
location: <unknown location>:-1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.90\2.90\scripts\startup\bl_ui\properties_constraint.py", line 127, in draw_header
    con = self.get_constraint(context)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.90\2.90\scripts\startup\bl_ui\properties_constraint.py", line 121, in get_constraint
    con = context.object.constraints[self.list_panel_index]
IndexError: bpy_prop_collection[index]: index 3 out of range, size 0

location: <unknown location>:-1

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

My timestamp 2021-10-20

Thanks for any explanation or fixes or suggestions.

Comment: How much older?  You might have to go back to 2.83 and open/save the file, guessing that 2.83 updated constraints in a way that 2.9 now assumes.

Comment: @MartyFouts  ⊚... Interesting idea ... is that a known technique to solve?  A known shortcoming of recent Blender? ⊚  Thanks.  It may take me 24 hours to do this .. due to scheduling ... Modified @ ‎December ‎‎2018,

Comment: It's not a common technique, no; more of a desperate last ditch effort.  I came across it when displacement nodes were changed between 2.78, 2.79, and 2.80.  2.80 couldn't handle 2.78 files, but 2.79 converted them into a form 2.80 could then handle.  It became moot when they fixed a bug in 2.80 but it got me through until then.

Comment: @MartyFouts Thanks for inside defect info.